# How to configure Mail service in laravel 5.4 while email client is webmail?

Tags: laravel-5.4, plesk

I have background of sending mail from SMTP driver. But currently I am working on a project where mail client is using webmail.DomainName.com (mail host starts with **webmail**) and website is hosted on Plesk Automation (web hosting Automation System like Cpanel). I can't send email from my own interface to other emails. actually this is my domain mail server which refuses sending mail.I already created a mail account I am using in .env file. But I don't know how to solve it and where I am doing wrong in my code.

This is my mail configuration function code in my mail controller

```
  public function mailSender(Request $request)
{
    $data = new EmailVarification();
    $data->email = $request['email'];
    $data->token = str_random(40);
    $data->save();
    $dataVar['token'] = $data->token;
    $dataVar['from'] = "MyEmail@MyDomain.com";
    $dataVar['email'] = "someOneEmail@SomeOneDomain.com";
    Mail::send('pages.registration.emailcon', $dataVar, function ($message) use ($dataVar) {
        $message->from($dataVar['from']);
        $message->to($dataVar['email']);
        $message->subject('Account Activation ');
    });
    return "saved";
}
```

For fast configuration I am using .nev file for mail and I my configuration in .env mail section is:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
MAIL_DRIVER=SMTP
MAIL_HOST=webmail.MyDomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MyEmail@MyDomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=MyEmailPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

While I am sending Email it gets me this error #screenshot
[image] 
As myself evaluation the problem is with part MAIL_DRIVER=SMTP in .env where webmail.MyDomain.com is not allowing or something else I don't know.

[image]

Comment: what is the problem I really didnt understand

Comment: hi Rodrane  sorry for that, now i updated my question you can see the error image

Comment: can you try `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: i did but still the same error message

Comment: try to put server IP instead of domain name `MAIL_HOST=192.168.1.1 (your.server.ip)`

Comment: well thank you Rodrane, just checked it still error Connection could not be established with host #my server ip and so on

Comment: i think #plesk using something else or some how privileges for sending mail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148951/discussion-between-anar-bayramov-and-hanif-formoly).

Comment: Hello, did you solve this ?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: We need to contact the domain provider to point the mail.domain.com to the server first, there will be 2 process, creating  an A record an MX record, hosting team will also instruct on how to do it. Or you will be getting : `Connection could not be established with host mail.domain.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start configuring the reset password. It's easier, you only need execute the commands laravel give us. In laravel 5.2 (i'm using) you need exucute this command for create the views to reset tthe forgotten passwords.

```
php artisan make:auth
```

And this command for execute the migration that create the tables of users and password reset.

```
php artisan migrate
```

After you have the views to reset and you can access to them; you need create a new email with your domain. I'm using "Hosting-México" (Hosting-México give me a cpanel for manage my domain), in my case when y create a new (from cpanel), only for send emails from backend, the cpanel give me specific information for configure mail account. This information you need put in your .env file.
[Creating mail account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5bD9.png)

My domain too use webmail like mail client. But the information that cpanel give me it has'nt similar to webmail.

This is the information that cpanel give me.

- User name: hello@mydomain.com
- Password: the password you configured for account
- Incoming server: visshnu.hosting-mexico.net, IMAP Port: ### POP3 Port: ###
- **Mail server: visshnu.hosting-mexico.net**, **SMTP Port: ###**

  And this is my .env file:

  MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

  MAIL_HOST=vishnu.hosting-mexico.net

  MAIL_PORT=###

  MAIL_USERNAME=hello@mydomain.com

  MAIL_PASSWORD=###########

  MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

How you can see the specific information the cpanel give me, it has'nt similar to webmail, although the mail server does use webmail.

Maybe the hosting serves as an intermediary and the data necessary to set up laravel has to be provided by your capnel.

I hope it helps you